# Ignore nested single quotes inside of single quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working with matching an entire string within single quotes. The problem is, these strings are dynamically generated and I need to ignore all other single quotes within the first set of quotes. I've come across other solutions that are similar but I can't seem to tweak them to my needs.

Here is what I've worked with so far:

```
'(?:''|[^'])*'
```

I would like to match essentially everything within the first and last single quotes between `content:` and `;`

Some example text:

```
@bottom {
      content: 'Here we have an embedded unescaped 'single' that is generated at runtime. {Let's ignore it
                please'
      ;
}
```

This is the playground I've been working in:
https://regex101.com/r/ITHciu/2

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regular expressions are intended for parsing regular grammars. Your grammar is irregular. It will be easier to give up regex.

Comment: What is generating this text, and why isn't it escaping the quotes ?

Comment: These are text files that people manually type up. I wish I could change the rules but this is what I'm given.

Comment: You would probably get some easier and more robust mileage, out of creating a simple text parser that counts in and out quotes, and and escapes those that are nested (potentially)

Comment: "these strings are dynamically generated" just tell whoever generates those string something not nice and let them fix they code...

Comment: In mean time please [edit] the question to explain how `content: ';content:;'''';;;;' ` should be handled and why.

Comment: @TheGeneral This is an interesting suggestion. I'll take a look at this approach.

Comment: @Poziki yeah i hadn't really put much thought into, counting obviously wont work like it would say brackets, however, you could just look for the first and last, and escape everything in between,

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov does this clarify the question matching?

Comment: No... It should be trivial to match example you have (by just literally matching expected start and end, allowing anything else in between), but I strongly suspect it is not what you are looking for...

Comment: `'.*'` matches everything between first and last quote (enable singleline). If you need anything else, you should be more specific about the rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to use Regexes for this *and* you are certain that `;` will not be *inside* the string you are searching for, you could try this: `'[^;]*'\s*;$`. It will select everything from a `'` and go until a like that ends with whitesapce and a `;`.

Edit: if you need the stuff between the `'` and `';`, you could use a group `'([^;]*)'\s*;$`.

However, a much cleaner solution would be to make a little parser, that will read the string char by char. It's a fun exercise if you got a little bit more time.

---

If nothing else, you could use that regex to *correct* the invalid syntax in your files. And tell the people manually writing them what the valid syntax should be.